# Get Aggregate Values of Each Column In a Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to Oracle; I want to be able to generate a report that gives me the aggregate values for each column on a table. I haven't found anything that does this automatically, so I created a table where I upload the columns names, then I am using the data in that table to build individual SQL Statements:

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE CARIAS.TEST_CA_1 
   (
    DATA_BASE_NAME VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
      SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
      TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
      FIELD_NAME VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   );
```

INSERT INTO TEST_CA_1 (DATA_BASE_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME, TABLE_NAME, FIELD_NAME) VALUES ('FDWP', 'FDW',  'D_CLAIM',  'FIELD_CLAIM_OFFICE');
INSERT INTO TEST_CA_1 (DATA_BASE_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME, TABLE_NAME, FIELD_NAME) VALUES ('FDWP', 'FDW',  'D_CLAIM',   'CLAIM_SYMBOL_CODE');
INSERT INTO TEST_CA_1 (DATA_BASE_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME, TABLE_NAME, FIELD_NAME) VALUES ('FDWP', 'FDW',  'D_CLAIM',  'HANDLING_DIVISION');

Here is the query that builds the statements:

```
SELECT 
FIELD_NAME,
SQL_STATEMENT
FROM       
(
--Creates Count Statements

SELECT 'SELECT ' || FIELD_NAME ||', COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM ' || SCHEMA_NAME || '.' || TABLE_NAME ||' GROUP BY ' || FIELD_NAME || ';' AS SQL_STATEMENT, FIELD_NAME FROM TEST_CA_1    
UNION ALL
```

--Creates MIN and MAX Values Statement

```
SELECT 'SELECT MIN(' || FIELD_NAME || ') AS MIN_VALUE, MAX(' || FIELD_NAME || ') AS MAX_VALUE FROM ' || SCHEMA_NAME || '.' || TABLE_NAME || ';' AS SQL_STATEMENT
      ,FIELD_NAME
FROM TEST_CA_1

)
ORDER BY FIELD_NAME;
```

Then I use those "built" statements to get what I want. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: An upvote for providing a test case, however, it is incomplete. Please post some insert statements as input data.It will be useful to the person willing to answer your question. Good luck!

Comment: The INSERT statement like that is invalid for Oracle.

Comment: The easier way would be to go to the Oracle system tables and query for database, table, and column names and types to build your statements.  Unfortunately I can only do this with SQL Server--I don't know anything about the system tables in Oracle (or else I'd post this as an answer).  I'm only posting this comment to provide a lead to someone who knows how to get to the Oracle system tables.

Comment: how would you find that aggregate value for a column of type VARCHAR2?  The question only seems to make sense for columns that contain numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first approach could be this:

```
create or replace function exec_on_table_field(i_table    in varchar2,
                                               i_field    in varchar2,
                                               i_function in varchar2)
  return clob is
  l_result clob;
begin
  execute immediate 'select to_clob(' || i_function || '(' || i_field ||
                    ')) from ' || i_table
    into l_result;
  return l_result;
end;
```

call this function with

```
select u.TABLE_NAME, u.COLUMN_NAME, 
to_char(exec_on_table_field(u.TABLE_NAME, u.COLUMN_NAME, 'min')), 
to_char(exec_on_table_field(u.TABLE_NAME, u.COLUMN_NAME, 'max')) from 
user_tab_cols u where u.TABLE_NAME like 'PS_CS%' and rownum < 5;
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Frank Ockenfuss worked great. I also found some of the information I was looking for by using the following Oracle View:

SELECT *

FROM ALL_TAB_COL_STATISTICS U

WHERE U.TABLE_NAME LIKE 'MY_TABLE_NAME';